# When Urge records are exist getting an StackOverFlow exception

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5, ado.net-entity-data-model

Here studenDetailsList are getting from database which consists of 30,000 records

```
Var studentDetailsList;
Foreach ( var stDetails in studentDetailsList)
{
     // Here i am inserting each student in to table
}
```

I am getting error has

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

What could be the problem ?

can anybody help

Comment: Please specify the source of the error ..

Answer (score 0):

Probably the answer is that there is a bug in this piece of code:

```
 // Here i am inserting each student in to table
```

However, as you choose not to post the actual code, no-one can say where the bug is.

Like as not, that piece of code is recursively calling the original function. However, you chose not to reveal the name of the original function :-(